# Не работает timeout

Tags: linux, perl, docker

Привет знатоки перла!

Пишу простейший скрипт для http get . Пытался пользоваться `HTTP::Tiny` и `LWP` но почему-то, в них не работает таймаут.
Смотрю с помощью `strace` свой скрипт, дело доходит до `connect(3, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(80), sin_addr=inet_addr("1.1.1.1")}, 16)` и тишина... спустя несколько минут таймаут конечно срабатывает, но меня это не устраивает, я задаю его в 1 секунду.

Пришлось использовать `IO::Socket::INET`

```
my @test = ('1.1.1.1');

foreach $i (@test) {
my $sock = new IO::Socket::INET (PeerAddr => $i,
                               PeerPort => "http(80)",
                               Timeout => 1);
next unless $sock;
$sock->autoflush(1);
$sock->print("GET /index.htm http/1.1\n\n");
my $dock = join("", $sock->getlines());
print "$dock\n";
}
```

Вот так работает без проблем. Почему?

P.S. Скрипт запускаю в докере в образе perl:5.20

Примеры того, что **не работает**...

```
use HTTP::Tiny;
  my $tiny = HTTP::Tiny->new(
                    agent           => 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)',
                    timeout         => 1,
                   );

my $response = $tiny->get('http://1.1.1.1/');

die "Failed!\n" unless $response->{success};

print "$response->{status} $response->{reason}\n";

while (my ($k, $v) = each %{$response->{headers}}) {
    for (ref $v eq 'ARRAY' ? @$v : $v) {
        print "$k: $_\n";
    }
}
```

и

```
use IO::Socket;
my $t = time;
my $sock = IO::Socket::Socks->new(
    ConnectAddr => '1.1.1.1', 
    ConnectPort => 80, 
    Timeout => 1
) or print "connection failed or timed out\n";

print "time: " . (time - $t) . "\n";
```

и ещё до кучи

```
use LWP::UserAgent
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
$ua->timeout(1);
my $response = $ua->get('http://1.1.1.1/');

if ($response->is_error) {
    printf "[%d] %s\n", $response->code, $response->message;

    # record the timeout
    if ($response->code == HTTP::Status::HTTP_REQUEST_TIMEOUT) {
        print "hello \n";
    }
}
```

Comment: первый пример выполняется ровно одну секунду, второй и третий содержат ошибки. дистрибутив: debian gnu/linux, версия 8.6; perl: версия 5.20.2, все библиотеки — из соответствующих пакетов.

Comment: Спасибо, в debian и у меня нормас всё выполняется. Я там написал где оно не работает... =\

Comment: вероятно, как-то неправильно собираете этот образ. впрочем, подозреваю, что вы не сами его собирали. тогда единственный разумный совет: соберите сами. это несложно.

Comment: В смысле "неправильно"? Как можно не правильно "собрать" `docker run --rm -it perl:5.20 bash` ? FACEPALM

Comment: @user245874 Проверил у себя ваш пример с LWP, дает таймаут ровно  через секунду, правда croak'ом до print helo не доходит

Comment: Превед @Mike ! А где Вы проверяли? И как...

Comment: *Как можно не правильно "собрать"* — легко и не напрягаясь. я понял — образ собирали не вы. второй (более длинный, и вряд ли чем-то вам полезный) вариант ваших действий — сообщите тому, кто собирал образ, о том, что такой-то код в этом образе работает неправильно.

Comment: Спасибо @alexanderbarakin ! Обязательно воспользуюсь Вашим советом (нет) , если не будет других!

Comment: @user245874 Ну как ... скопировал ваш последний пример в файл, добавил точку с запятой после use. Запустил на одном из своих серверов под gentoo. Получил ответ `[500] Can't connect to 1.1.1.1:80 (timeout)` через секунду после запуска. поменял таймаут на 3 секунды, завершилось с той же ошибкой через 3 ... как бы проблем не заметил, надо видимо обрабатывать croack что бы выполнять свои действия по таймауту

Comment: Эх-х, и на gentoo у меня это тоже работает. Ай ладно, не тратьте время, тут видимо слишком много всего надо дебажить...

Comment: @user245874 Ну это странно, что оно не работает под конкретной средой. по моему пониманию либо libc данной среды должна криво отработать таймаут, что кажется маловероятным, либо в ней должна быть какая то особенно кривая версия каких то перловых библиотек.

Comment: Да ладно, буду значит юзать `IO::Socket::INET` мне просто из академического интереса хотелось узнать в чём разница. У меня даже этим методом скрипт долго отрабатывает в контейнере в отличии от того, как если бы он был просто в системе. Вариантов почему такое происходит - миллионы.

Comment: У вас может исполтзоваться прокси или такие настройки файрвола, что одна библиотека с ники справляется, а у другой банально нет поддержки или необходимо установить какую-нибудь переменную окружения...